# How to vertically align items in a React Bootstrap Table row

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap

I want to center the content in a React Bootstrap Table row, along the y-axis.

Here's the code I currently have:

```js
import React from "react";
import { ThreeDots } from "react-bootstrap-icons";

return (
<Table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Question</th>
      <th>Answer</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Define inflation</td>
      <td>Inflation is the rate of increase ...</td>
      <td><ThreeDots/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</Table>
);
```

Here's what I tried:

```js
import React from "react";
import { ThreeDots } from "react-bootstrap-icons";

return (
<Table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Question</th>
      <th>Answer</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr className="d-flex align-items-center">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Define inflation</td>
      <td>Inflation is the rate of increase ...</td>
      <td><ThreeDots/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</Table>
);
```

I added `className="d-flex align-items-center"` to the `<tr>` element.

But the table's borders gets all funky & jumbled up, anyone know what i can do to fix this?

---

### Update

Okay i figured out using the class `align-middle` can vertically center the content of a table cell, as per Boostrap [doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/vertical-align/).

Does anyone know if there is a CSS/Bootstrap styling that I can apply to the table row or table so that all rows are vertically centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the CSS code you can use to define the `d-flex align-items-center` class:

```css
/* Custom CSS */
.d-flex {
  display: flex !important;
}

.align-items-center {
  align-items: center !important;
}
```

Add this CSS code to your project's stylesheet. Make sure to include this stylesheet in your project's HTML file so that the custom CSS rules are applied to the table cells as intended. This will help you achieve the desired vertical alignment within the table cells while preserving the table's layout and borders.

**For the updated question:**

To vertically center all rows within a Bootstrap table, you can apply the `align-middle` class to the `<tr>` elements directly within the `<tbody>` section. This will vertically center the content of all cells in each row. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
import React from "react";
import { ThreeDots } from "react-bootstrap-icons";

return (
  <Table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Question</th>
        <th>Answer</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr className="align-middle">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Define inflation</td>
        <td>Inflation is the rate of increase ...</td>
        <td><ThreeDots /></td>
      </tr>
      {/* Add more rows here */}
    </tbody>
  </Table>
);
```

By adding the `align-middle` class to the `<tr>` elements within the `<tbody>`, you ensure that all rows' content is vertically centered in each cell. This provides a consistent vertical alignment across all rows in the table.

Comment: thank you Shila! I just had to add the `align-middle` class to `tr` & all `td` elements were vertically aligned!

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align` property should be put on `td` and not `tr`, because it defines how the object relates to it's parent. But you can use proper css selector to apply it.

```
table td {
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer Alex! indeed the `vertical-align` CSS property was what I was looking for, but as I am using Bootstrap, the Bootstrap property I am looking for is `align-middle`

Answer (score 1):

Add the `align-middle` bootstrap class to all of the `td` elements. Or define a custom component to pass the data to that has the class already applied.

Comment: yes that's right Rawley, I had to add the `align-middle` class, thank you!